# A function that is measurable on $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, continuity, measurable-functions, borel-sets

This seems to be a result that is used often, which I am having difficulty proving. There may be a more general statement, but I'll write out the statement that I was trying to prove:

> Let $f:(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be a function that is continuous on a set $A \in  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which may not necessarily be continuous on $A^c$. Then, $f \chi_{A}$ is measurable in $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$, where $\chi$ is the indicator function.

My attempt was to start on the set $A$ and artificially 'extend' $f \chi_{A}$ continuously to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I met many difficulties, as the set $A$ may not be convex, and in general borel sets are hard to visualize. Does this have a neat solution?

Comment: Let me add a comment to further clarify: $f$ need not be borel measurable. All we know is that $f$ is continuous on $A$. $f$ may not be continuous on $A^c$, and may behave very erratically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct approach:

**EDITED ANSWER**

Since $f\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&x\in A\\0&x\notin A\end{cases}$, take $a\in\Bbb  R$.

If $a> 0$, then $$\{f\chi_A(x)< a\}=\{x\in A:\, f(x)< a\}\cup A^c$$
Since $f$ is continuous on $A$, the first set is a (relative) open set on $A$, so measurable ($A$ is measurable). So both sets are measurables and we are done.

Now, if $a\le 0$, then $$\{f\chi_A(x)< a\}=A\cap\{f(x)<a\}$$ and again is measurable using the same argument above.

---

**PREVIOUS (not correct) ANSWER**

If $a\ge 0$, then $$\{f\chi_A(x)\le a\}=\{x\in A:\, f(x)\le a\}\cup A^c=(A\cap\{f(x)\le a\})\cup A^c$$ and this set is measurable since both $A$ and $f$ so are.

Now, if $a<0$, then $$\{f\chi_A(x)\le a\}=A\cap\{f(x)\le a\}$$ and again is measurable since $A$ and $f$ are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like you are using that $f$ is measurable. Could you clarify this? I do not think it is possible to deduce this from the statement of the question.

Comment: $f$ need not be measurable here.

Comment: @Albert I write again my answer. Now I think it is correct

Comment: @TitoEliatron $\{x\in A:\, f(x)< a\}$ is an open set in $A$, and therefore there exists an open set in $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $B \cap A = \{x\in A:\, f(x)< a\}$. As $A, B$ are in the borel sigma algebra, then so is $\{x\in A:\, f(x)< a\}$. This is what you mean, right? (I already did +1, so I can't do it twice--thanks again for your answer!)

Comment: Yes @Albert. That's what  I meant

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a set which is not Borel. Let $f=\chi_A$. Then $f$ is continuous on $A$ (w.r.t the realtive topology from $\mathbb R^{n}$ or any other topology!). But $f\chi_A=\chi_A$ is not Borel measurable since the inverse image of $\{1\}$ is  not  Borel set. Hence, neither $f$ nor  $f\chi_A$ has to be  measruable.

However, if $A$ is  a Borel set then $f$ and $f\chi_A$ are Borel meaurable: For any open set $U$ in the real line $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set in $A$ which means there is an open set $V$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ such that $f^{-1}(U)=A\cap V$. It folows that $f^{-1}(U)$ is Borel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1). Let me try to understand your answer: $\{f \chi_A = \chi_A\} = (\{f^{-1}(1) \} \cap A) \cup A^c$, and as $f$ is continuous there exists a closed set $B$ in e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $B \cap A = f^{-1}(1) \cap A$. I don't know how to proceed; in particular, I do not know the proof of the statement that if we take union/intersection of a measurable set with a non-measurable set, then the result is also non-measurable set. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You are complicating things. I am just saying that $f^{-1} (\{1\}=A$ which is not   a Borel set. This implies that $f$ is not measurable becasue $\{1\}$ is a Borel set.